# Right-to-Left Arabic translation with English letters displaying incorrectly on Android (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, localization

I have a translation for Urdu (India) that is displaying improperly on a Xamarin.Android application. This translation displays on a screen where the user must reset his/her PIN and needs to confirm the PIN. It displays, correctly, as so in our database:

‏`کی تصدیق کریں‏‏ PIN`

This is also retrieved from our database on the mobile device and comes out in the same way (you can see where I tried to add the RTL mark character to no avail):

[image: Correct translation]

However, when displaying on the actual application, it is displayed like this:

[image: Incorrect display]

I have tried setting TextDirection to "AnyRtl" and "Locale" and this still displays improperly. As you can see in the first picture, I also tried adding an RTL mark to the beginning of the text, and that did nothing either. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can open an issue in Github to check if it is a problem in Xamarin.Android. One workaround I think is use two edittext to display English letters and Arabic letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this:

1. Start the string with U+202 RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE
2. Then add U+202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
3. Then add your left-to-right text
4. End your left-to-right text with U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING

See below:
‮‪PIN‬ کی تصدیق کریں

Comment: Thanks for this.... it didn't end up being exactly this that worked for me, but it *was* a combination of RTL/LTR/POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING marks that made it work. So this method is definitely the accepted method.